How to judge the model's confidence in Learning-To-Rank (LTR)?
Recently I have been working on Learning-To-Rank model. I think it's very useful for my purpose, but how can we extract information regarding its confidence and accuracy? Specifically, I am using the Python package xgbranker and I would like to know

If we can retrieve the 'second-best' ordering prediction
Confidence interval of some kind

